# Additional Space after Colon in References

Tags: spacing, natbib

I'm printing the references in my document using:

```
\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\bibliography{D:/economics/dataset}
```

Here is one example of the generated references.

> George J. Borjas. Ethnicity, neighborhoods, and human-capital
>   externalities. American Economic Review, 85(3):365-390, 1995.

How can I insert a space between the “:” and page number for each reference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this formatting is controlled by functions in the file `plainnat.bst`.  two functions may be involved:

- `FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}`
- `FUNCTION {format.vol.num.eid}`

in the code block for each of these there is a line containing a colon:

- `{ ":\penalty0 " * pages n.dashify * }`
- `{ ":\penalty0 " * eid * }`

in both of these, the idea is to replace the `\penalty0` after the colon by a space.

if you choose this method of making the change, copy the file `plainnat.bst` into the directory in which the job is being run, rename it to `myplainnat.bst` and then make the changes.  also change

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

to

```
\bibliographystyle{myplainnat}
```

in your `tex` file.

there may be an easier way to do this, but i sometimes suffer from a "hacker" complex.

**EDIT:** a similar change was requested for the file `jpe.bst` (for the journal of political economy).  this `.bst` file is constructed in quite a different manner, and i'm not certain the comparable change will have the desired result.  nonetheless, here is a suggestion.

in the definition of

```
FUNCTION {format.journal.pages}
```

there is a line

```
 ":" *
```

simply add a space after the colon, within the quotes.  that will force a space into the expanded bib items.  as with `plainnat.bst`, whenever making such a change, write out the changed file with a new name.

**caution:** if the manuscript using this is being submitted to a journal that has its own idea of what style is wanted, any change may be refused.

Comment: Hi barbara, Thanks for your instruction. It works for me. I have another bst file. Could you take a look at how to solve the same problem for this bst file.

Comment: @Wonder -- i see that you've deleted some material.  have you solved the problem?

Comment: I have solved the problem for the plainnat.bst, but not for another bst file. Could I send you a bst file or I should post the code here? This bst file is the reference style for the Journal of Political Economy.

Comment: @Wonder -- please name the `.bst` file and give a link where it can be accessed.

Comment: I appreciate your help. The name of the `.bst` file is **jpe.bst**. You should find this file in the following link: [bst link](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/economic).

Comment: your professional advice has solved my problem perfectly. I appreciate your time and instruction. Best regards.

Comment: @Wonder -- if the suggestions have solved your problem, you can "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark at the left of the answer.

Comment: Hi Barbara, could I ask you one more question? The `jpe.bst`I mentioned before uses a underline to suppress authors' name if multiple papers written by the same authors appear in the reference. I wanna show authors' name for every paper. How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: @Wonder -- in the file `jpe.bst` there is a section `FUNCTION {name.or.dash}`.  within this section is a line `{ "---{}---{}---" }`.  replace this line by a copy of the next line: `{ s 'oldname := s }`.  i *think* this is the easiest (if not the most efficient) way to get rid of the 3-em dash that is substituted for identical author names.  not tested, and not guaranteed, but it looks like a reasonable approach.

Comment: Many thanks for this professional suggestion. It works perfectly for me.